# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First I'll put out the layout of my problem:

```
interface FilteredProducts {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: object;
    };
};
```

I initialise *filterProducts* to an empty object because the only time I put values in it is in an if, so I need to do that for later use

```
products: FilteredProducts
let filteredProducts: object = {};
```

Here I assign an object to filterProducts ->

```
if (filters.season && filters.dimension) {
        filteredProducts = (products[filters.season] || {})[filters.dimension];
    };
```

If a specific filter is set I want to delete a property of this object

```
if (productKey && Object.entries(filteredProducts).length > 0) {
       delete filteredProducts[productKey];
}
```

The problem is that it says that:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

when I try to delete this key.

I tried to set the type for *filteredProducts* ->

```
interface FilteredInterface {
    [key: string]: object;
}
```

But then I get

> Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'FilteredInterface'.
> Index signature is missing in type '{}'.

When I try to assign that object to filterProducts. (the code in the first *if*)

Here is the full code for this part:

```
interface FilteredProducts {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: object;
    };
};

const filter = (products: FilteredProducts, filters: UserFiltersInterface): object => {
    let filteredProducts: FilteredInterface = {};
    // console.log('products', products);
    // console.log('filters', filters);
    if (filters.season && filters.dimension) {
        filteredProducts = (products[filters.season] || {})[filters.dimension];
    };
    if (filters.tire_size) {
        // console.log('filteredProducts tire_size', filters.tire_size);
        if (Object.entries(filteredProducts).length > 0) {
            // console.log('filteredProducts', filteredProducts);
            if (filters.tire_size !== 'all') {
                Object.entries(filteredProducts).forEach((product) => {
                    const productKey: string = product[0];
                    const productInfo = product[1];
                    if (productInfo.size !== filters.tire_size) {
                        if (productKey && Object.entries(filteredProducts).length > 0) {
                            delete filteredProducts[productKey];
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        };
    };
    // console.log('filteredProducts', filteredProducts);
    return filteredProducts;
};
```

Comment: Please bring these various isolated code blocks together into a cohesive [mcve] demonstrating the problem. (Ideally, also include a link to a runnable copy of the problem in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). But be sure the code is **in** the question as well.)

Comment: `let filteredProducts: { [key: string]: object } = { };`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I tried that when I made it of type


```interface FilteredInterface {
    [key: string]: object;
}``` 

Doesn't work

Comment: Instead of delete I tried to do ```filterProducts[productKey] = undefined```

But it tells me that I cannot assign undefined to readOnly property
But filterProducts isn't a const ?

Comment: You must have a problem somewhere else... The `delete` option is better. Don't use `object` when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that what you want to be returned `(products[filters.season])[filters.dimension]` is a `FilteredInterface` object. Because you want to store it in `filteredProducts: FilteredInterface`.

You can do it here (replace `object`):

```
interface FilteredProducts {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: FilteredInterface;
    };
};
```

Or here (a cast, and you keep the `object` in `FilteredProducts`:

```
filteredProducts = (products[filters.season])[filters.dimension] as FilteredInterface;
```

Edit: see this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaShAJgBSgHtcBXBMAZ2QG8AoZR5AbQGsIBPALmUrClABzALo96TCS3bde-IaOREARgCsIFANwMmAXy166dUNnhJkhEuTC1tjSsABeEHnwEhBdHYePRTKdFjQeACS4L6IKOJMbJwucu4KFmSant5hsBFomNjUUXYQcJREIHFuggA0tsi4wAC2ECD2xaVClRJgwDgA%20vZOLe6pdAjFfMgw2dDIALzIABQADsTJVDwB2HhJVpTlYxNQlKt7lACUPMpqFNMAfDYSGBDW44E4BEtbh88h6X7TtAYSAHoAchho0iPcAHQYIiCWYAckWlgolDhO0RyxOWkBwNBRUh0NhcKeOVRu2emKqwBgc2J0EoEMoBSKIGQADJWWSchCavVGsBisdbpJGLSXptkb8Fm9kcxRfTGYVisJjrKjty6g0miBhMhCllPrhQiYIljdKbGFSaWqOt1ehBBXlJECQSNwRAoTD4aKNtKqMgbRAeo4IKS5RCA0GnMdzZJLbMAPKqdRgCENOQQSizb2vJFUY5QhqCMAAC2QNwADA6qsLGM7cW6PYTs%20KqKG9j7cxSa7HqVnrZ1A3bkABCKYzOFwDAYOFV7vdxMXFNpgQZvsGlsnCEwIhQACiiGLsylucFUxujrnNdx1nRVgA0rFZGVfreKMxy8IY5fhdfkK%20wKE24vr6zAAIyftW34SHG-6AUQDLBiOY6cnS4YDpG9pClBl4wb6D4cGyHILsmqbgCumbNr6m73O4JZlsglZYdhUG4BA9yQChYpUcw-74RBzGXl4AmSEJAk6NGkHCv8NbSYwsnIHWrr4p6RLtjmGJtuuVESRIOBgKQUAspRnb6BoQA)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The only problem left is that it says that it can't delete the property or I can't assign to it because it's read only. But the object isn't a const. Any idea why ?

Comment: I have no idea... look at the playground in my edited answer, it seems to work fine.

Comment: It does work :) Thank you ! Appreciate the quick reply